# send data from html to swf

Tags: html, actionscript-3

beside swfaddress is there any other way to send data from a html page to a swf application? What I need is when a user clicks on html contents to change information inside the swf.

Thanks

Comment: I might have found a possible solution, using ExternalInterface, this is from adob website:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html
"From JavaScript on the HTML page, you can call an ActionScript function in Flash Player. The ActionScript function can return a value, and JavaScript receives it immediately as the return value of the call."

Comment: Mhm, that's how ExternalInterface works. -pokes answer-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html). You can set up callbacks in the SWF that allow you to use Javascript to call your Actionscript functions.